How to query a list of strings field in an Amplify DataStore model using a String value
I have the following models:
type Activity @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: private, ownerField: "pOwner" }]) {
    id: ID!
    friendsListID: ID @index(name: "byFriendsList", sortKeyFields: ["id"])
    friendsList: FriendsList @belongsTo(fields: ["friendsListID"])
    pOwner: String!
}

type FriendsList @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: private, ownerField: "pOwner" }]) {
    id: ID!
    friendsIds: [String!]!
    pOwner: String!
}

I'm trying to query Activity using the friendsId that's stored on FriendsList:
FriendsList contains:
'friendsList_id1' | ['friends_id1', 'friends_id2'] | 'owner_id1'
While Activity contains:
'activity_id1' | 'friendsList_id1' | 'owner_id1'
The Amplify query I want to do something like the following, but it's not allowed:
List<Activity> activities = await Amplify.DataStore.query(Activity.classType, where: Activity.FRIENDSLIST.FRIENDSLISTIDS.eq('query_id');
···

What can I try to make this work?

